# Set ViewPager Tab / PageTitle width

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My default ViewPager with two Tab items looks like:

[image]

The blue selection is not drawn to the edge (has an empty space), how can I align it to the left (selecting the USERS Tab, one have the same problem but there is a black space on the right hand side instead)?

The sample app from Android http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging has the same problem.

With three items and above the problem seems to go away.

(As a follow up, can one set the Height of the Tab? Change the Blue color?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this works on a Samsung Galaxy S III mini. I suspect this is a bug on my device Nexus 4 LG. Will file a bug report.

Still interested in how you can change the height, width and color of the Tab though?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a 2012 Nexus 7 (4.4.2) and Nexus 4 (4.4.4) yet works fine on a Nexus 5 (4.4.4) - would love to hear why this is happening

Comment: The [Google I/O 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched&hl=en) app uses ViewPager tabs in the *My Schedule* activity and looks fine across all of my devices.  

It looks as if they have overcome the problem using their [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)  

I'll take a look myself later...